# Custom HTML Progress bar with marks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to figure out the best way to go about making a progress bar/timeline that allows me to create markings (white lines indicated in the picture below) when the user clicks the button. I have researched a bit into HTML5 cavas and some custom jquery stuff. I wanted to see if anyone has specific recommendations on what would be the best approach?

[image]

Thank you.
John

Comment: Use the bootstrap framework for the look and feel. http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress

Comment: StackOverflow is for specific code-related help, not generalized recommendations.

Comment: @Diodeus it's a good thing that this is code related then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you use bootstrap, I have recently used it for the same purpose and it looks great.

You can find it on this page:

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/

and an example of how it works here:

http://getbootstrap.com/components/

good luck!

edit: specific one I used: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress-striped

Comment: Would you be open to sharing what you created. I would love to see what it looks like @Sam Creamer

Comment: I can do so on monday, when the product launches that it is used in!